# unable to fetch latest attribute value in lightning

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-community

I have picklist in lightning. On onchange fuction it is getting a data from apex method and setting it in a attribute. And just after that when i trying to fetch the value of that attribute. I am getting undefind. After another onchange . I am the getting the value of the attribute but the previous one not the latest.

```
<lightning:select aura:id="selectListView" name="View" label="View :"  class="select" onchange="{!c.onChange}">
        <option value="">--None--</option>
        <aura:iteration var="option" items="{!v.Options}">
            <option value="{!option.Id}">{!option.Name}</option>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

//on select change

```
onSelectChange : function(component, event, sortField) {

    // set field name input attribute
    var inputAction = component.get("c.GetFieldNameString");
    console.log(component.find('selectListView').get('v.value'));
    inputAction.setParams({
        viewId : component.find('selectListView').get('v.value')
    });

    inputAction.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log(a.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.fieldNamesInput", a.getReturnValue());
        } 

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(inputAction);

    //get list of field names

    var fieldsListAction = component.get("c.FieldNames");
    var inputString = component.get("v.fieldNamesInput");
    console.log(inputString);
    fieldsListAction.setParams({
        input : inputString
    });

    fieldsListAction.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.fieldNames", a.getReturnValue());

        } 

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(fieldsListAction);
```

debug
_

```
a0F1q000000UXiJEAW
TransactionsDetail.js:91 undefined
TransactionsDetail.js:80 Name,currencyisocode,akritiv__group_amount__c,akritiv__group_currency__c,akritiv__transaction_key__c,akritiv__balance__c,payer_customer_no__c,project_name__c,akritiv__source_system__c,akritiv__status__c,akritiv__Notes__c
TransactionsDetail.js:73 a0F1q000000UWJDEA4
TransactionsDetail.js:91 Name,currencyisocode,akritiv__group_amount__c,akritiv__group_currency__c,akritiv__transaction_key__c,akritiv__balance__c,payer_customer_no__c,project_name__c,akritiv__source_system__c,akritiv__status__c,akritiv__Notes__c
TransactionsDetail.js:80 Name,akritiv__balance__c,akritiv__source_system__c,akritiv__batch_number__c,akritiv__Notes__c
```

var inputString = component.get("v.fieldNamesInput"); should have returned the value on first click itself instead of undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server actions (fired with `$A.enqueueAction()`) are *asynchronous*. The information is not available to you until they execute later in the lifecycle and execute the callback you provide.

To look at a skeleton of your code:

```
inputAction.setCallback(this, function(a) {
    if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
        component.set("v.fieldNamesInput", a.getReturnValue());
    } 

});
$A.enqueueAction(inputAction);
var inputString = component.get("v.fieldNamesInput");
```

The data population

```
        component.set("v.fieldNamesInput", a.getReturnValue());
```

does not execute until (1) the asynchronous call to the server completes successfully and (2) the callback method is executed.

But the data *access*

```
var inputString = component.get("v.fieldNamesInput");
```

takes place immediately after *enqueuing* the server action - synchronously. The data is not there yet for it to reference. You'll need to execute your second server action after the first one completes (possibly by placing the call within the callback from the first action), or restructure your Apex so that you only need to make one server round trip.

Comment: Hey David , Thank you so much . Can you please help me with some sample code for this statement "placing the call within the callback from the first action" ? It would be a great help .

Comment: @Cooolranjan I'm just saying that you need to move your code for the second server action inside the callback from your first action.